# R Tidyverse: how to create a weighted count table of multiple factor variables

Tags: r, count, tidyverse, weighted

This question relates to summarising survey results

The case is where there are multiple variants of the same question
so

```
df <- data.frame(
    survey_question_subquestionA = c("Less","More","Less","More","Missing","More",Less") 
    survey_question_subquestionB = c("Less","More","Less","More","Missing","More",Less")
    survey_question_subquestionC = c("Less","More","Less","More","Missing","More",Less")
    survey_weights = c( 1.02, 1.05, 0.97, 0.92, 0.94, 1.03, 0.98 )
```

The objective is to end up with a table

|  | More | Less | Missing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| subquestionA | n | n | n |
| subquestionB | n | n | n |
| subquestionC | n | n | n |
| Total | n | n | n |

```
qn <- "Question"
wt <- "Survey_Weights"
tvdf |> filter(Question == qn) |> select(Variable) |> unlist() |> unname() -> CVL
```

In real life I extract the variable names from another dataframe containing meta information called tvdf and the data frame itself has lots of other questions and surveys in it.

This works for unweighted counts

```
df |> select(any_of(CVL)) |> pivot_longer(cols = contains(qn), names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Values") |> group_by(Variable) |> count(Values) |> pivot_wider(names_from = Values, values_from = n) -> table
```

the problem is

```
count(Values, wt = get(wt))
```

doesnt work because they were excluded at select stage. If I include them they end up in my table.

Any suggestions welcome. I'm open to data.table solutions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?
For the addition of the "Total" row, I used the `janitor` package which has a handy function `adorn_totals()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 4.2.1
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.2.1
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.2.1
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.2.1
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 4.2.1
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.2.1
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 4.2.1
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 4.2.1

df <- tibble(
  survey_question_subquestionA = c("Less",
                                   "More",
                                   "Less",
                                   "More",
                                   "Missing",
                                   "More",
                                   "Less"),
  survey_question_subquestionB = c("Less", "More", "Less", "More", "Missing", "More", "Less"),
  survey_question_subquestionC = c("Less",
                                   "More",
                                   "Less",
                                   "More",
                                   "Missing",
                                   "More",
                                   "Less"),
  survey_weights = c(1.02, 1.05, 0.97, 0.92, 0.94, 1.03, 0.98)
)

df |>
  pivot_longer(cols = 1:3,
               names_to = "question") |>
  count(question, value, wt = survey_weights) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = value,
              values_from = n) |> 
  janitor::adorn_totals()
#>                      question Less Missing More
#>  survey_question_subquestionA 2.97    0.94    3
#>  survey_question_subquestionB 2.97    0.94    3
#>  survey_question_subquestionC 2.97    0.94    3
#>                         Total 8.91    2.82    9
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: so the trick is limiting the columns in the pivot_longer(). Thanks for that,